# Mostrar post de WordPress en una aplicacion android

Tags: android, wordpress, webservice

Tengo una duda sobre como puedo mostrar contenido de una pagina echa en WordPress, no me refiero a usar WebViews en Android, me refiero a que cuando yo publico algo en mi pagina pueda recuperar ese post y mostrarlo en una aplicación, no se si exista un API que me permita manejar el contenido de mi sitio web, me refiero a lo siguiente, yo en WordPress puedo publicar una entrada que puede ser visto por todos los usuarios o solamente algunos dependiendo los privilegios pero algunas de estas entradas tienen un PDF o una imagen, como podría yo mostrar el contenido en una aplicación o forzosamente debo usar un WebView.

Ese es un Post de prueba que cree para poder explicarme mejor, quiero cargar un contenido similar a como se ve pero sin usar WebViews.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te refieres a obtener los posts en formato json para poder utilizarlos?

Comment: Si asi es, el problema es que algunos post tienen imagenes o pdf no se como hacerlo

Comment: mi primer idea fue crear un web service y cargarlo en el sitio y que se conectara a la bd donde se guardan pero para mostrar imagenes uso piccaso pero no se que hacer con los pdf registrados

Comment: Has estado utilizando la propia api de wordpress para obtener los posts?

Comment: No apenas estaba revisando esa API, pero quiera saber si hay mas opciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes obtener las publicaciones en formato json en la siguiente ruta:

> tu-dominio/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/

Añadiendo un numero de id podrás obtener un post especifico. Si necesitas también acceder a las imágenes o pdfs, si estos están subidos en el wordpress, también puedes acceder a ellos mediante la ruta

> tu-dominio/wp-json/wp/v2/media/{id}

De esta manera puedes obtener el enlace donde descargar la imagen/pdf o la url a esta.

Aún así, la API de las publicaciones te devuelve un array con los archivos adjuntos como la imagen destacada, etc. Para facilitarte la obtención de los recursos.

En esta web puedes obtener mas información acerca de la API:

[Wordpress API Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/)

Comment: Entonces esta API o plugin lo puedo instalar desde mi panel de administracion de WordPress verdad?

Comment: No es necesario, viene de base en wordpress, accede a tu wordpress añadiendo la ruta y veras que te devuelve json